# APC SC450RM1U EPO port

Tags: ups

I'm looking to get a couple of the APC SC450RM1U UPS's, and within the specifications APC states that EPO is 'Optional' on this UPS.

I've had a look through the documentation, and it doesn't describe anywhere how to enable or connect an EPO switch to this UPS, whether it be via an add-in module or otherwise.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I've forwarded this question to APC, hopefully they'll come back with an answer :D

Answer (score 0):

So this is what APC come back with:

> Apology for the confusion.
>
> The SC450RMI1U does not have an option to have EPO. We already excalated this information > > listed in our web site to our IT guys to remove it from the technical specification of the > > said model.
>
> Again my apology.

Kinda sucks, but at least there's an answer Lol ...